# How to automate Hyper-V Snapshots?

Tags: hyper-v, automation, snapshot

I have a Windows 2008 server with two virtual machines in Hyper-V, how can I automate the process of taking a daily snapshot and automatically deleting those older than 7 days?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using snapshots as backups?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you'll end up using powershell - [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/cc952342.aspx)'s a first stepping stone.